# How to override existing Hibernate Validator?

Tags: hibernate-validator

I would like to override the built-in validator of `@Email`.

Reason: The built-in validator implements deprecated RFC 2822. I want to create custom validator that implements RFC 5322.

I know [how to create custom constrain annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-simple) e.g. `@EmailRFC5322` with its validator, but I want to use existing `@Email` annotation with custom validator.

Answer (score 2):

Custom validators for existing constraints can be provided either programmatically:

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
    .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
    .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
    .constraintDefinition( Email.class )
    .includeExistingValidators( false )
    .validatedBy( MyEmailValidator.class );

configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping );
```

Or it can also be done through xml:

```
<constraint-definition annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL">
  <validated-by include-existing-validators="false">
     <value>org.hibernate.validator.constraintvalidators.RegexpURLValidator</value>
  </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
```

See this part of the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-constraint-definition) for more details